# Joi conditional based on value of it's key (self-reference)

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

I have an existing schema like this

```
exports.updateSchema = Joi.object({
  class_id: Joi.string().guid({ version: 'uuidv4' }).required(),
});
```

Existing only allow uid value, but now I also wanna allow specific string like `general`.
So I need a schema that has conditional based on it's value, if try many ways using `ref` like this

```
exports.updateSchema = Joi.object({
  class_id: Joi.string().when(
    Joi.ref('.class_id'), {
      not: Joi.string().guid({ version: 'uuidv4' }),
      then: Joi.string().valid('general').required(),
      otherwise: Joi.string().guid({ version: 'uuidv4' }).required(),
    },
  ),
});
```

but no one works well.

And also tried this one

```
exports.updateGradeParamsSchema = Joi.object({
  class_id: Joi.string(),
}).when(Joi.object({ class_id: 'general' }).unknown(), {
  then: Joi.object({
    class_id: Joi.string().valid('general').required()
  }),
  otherwise: Joi.object({
    class_id: Joi.string().guid({ version: 'uuidv4' }).required()
  }),
```

but the error message is confusing, when I input 'john-doe', it's return

> ""class_id" must be a valid GUID"

instead of `"class_id\" must be [general]`

Is anyone ever do `self-reference` in Joi or is there another solutions for this?

> UPDATE

Best approach

```
exports.updateSchema = Joi.object({
    class_id: Joi.alternatives().conditional('class_id', {
      not: Joi.string().guid({ version: 'uuidv4' }),
      then: Joi.string().valid('general').required(),
      otherwise: Joi.string().guid({ version: 'uuidv4' }).required()
    })
});
```

based on docs [here](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#alternatives) it said this `will use the first matching schema, ignoring other conditional statements`

cons:

- If I input uuid v1, it will match the first schema because the uuid is treat as string, and return `\"class_id\" must be [general]` instead of `\"class_id\" must be a valid GUID`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
exports.updateSchema = Joi.object({
  grade_id: Joi.alternatives().try(
    Joi.string().guid({ version: 'uuidv4' }),
    Joi.string().valid('general')
  ).required()
});
```

This uses the alternatives method to try both guid validation for UUIDs and valid validation for the string "general". The required method is used to ensure that grade_id is present in the data.

I hope this helps!

If you want to return custom message:

```
exports.updateSchema = Joi.object({
  grade_id: Joi.string().when(
    Joi.ref('.grade_id'), {
      not: Joi.string().guid({ version: 'uuidv4' }),
      then: Joi.string().valid('general').required()
        .message('Grade ID must be a UUID or the string "general"'),
      otherwise: Joi.string().guid({ version: 'uuidv4' }).required()
        .message('Grade ID must be a UUID'),
    },
  ),
});
```

Comment: This one works exactly like my second sample, yours more simple and easier to understand. But the issue is the error message, is it possible to custom message if I use yours?

Comment: I've tried the custom message, but it can't run and return error `Cannot apply rules to empty ruleset or the last rule added does not support rule properties`. I've tried to use `messages({})` instead. But the problem is that the validation not working as I expect. Consider I remove the custom message, if I input `john-doe`, it will return `\"class_id\" must be a valid GUID` which I think ther right one should be `"class_id\" must be [general]`

Comment: I've update the post, added the best approach I can do for now. May be there's another suggestion from you